# Data-structure for a priority queue with element uniqueness based on an element field

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm programming an implementation of the Basic Theta* path planning algorithm in Java right now. I have a class called `Vertex` which is effectively a 3D point in space (`location`), a pointer to another vertex (`parent`), a float for the direct distance to the goal vertex (`distanceToGoalVertex`) and a float for the distance along the path from the vertex to the start vertex (`distanceToStartVertex`, found by following successive parent pointers and computing the total distance).

In another class, I'm manipulating vertices in an environment with obstacles to find a path from the start vertex to the goal vertex. A data-structure called `open` is used to hold vertices which have been marked for expansion but not yet expanded. To expand a vertex means to look at the 8 surrounding vertices (on a grid) and add them to `open`. The problem here is that when I expand a vertex I will get a collection of vertices, where at least one vertex in this collection will return the original vertex when it's expanded. This will lead to an infinite loop and is therefore unacceptable. To overcome this I need a way to add to `open` only Vertices which have not been visited previously. The problem is I can't rely on the `equals()` method of `Vertex` since `distanceToStartVertex` will change with each iteration as the path taken to get to the start vertex grows. It seems the only option is to use the location of the vertex.

Ultimately I need a collection for `open` which allows me to sort elements using a comparator (which I've already made, no problems there) and can reject duplicates based purely on location. The data-structure also needs to have methods to return the element which minimises the comparator. I've thought about extending `PriorityQueue` and overriding the methods which add elements to check the location of all elements before adding, but this seems like it will be very inefficient. How should I make the data-structure in a way that won't compromise efficiency?

Comment: why don't you add `visited` attribute to `Vertex` class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems almost ideal for a `TreeSet` except for the condition that

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal.

This means that your condition of a excluding methods solely by location will not work.

One option would be to create a thin wrapper class around `TreeMap`.

```
public class VertexSet {
  private TreeMap<Location, Vertex> treeMap; //todo: instantiate w/ comparator in constructor

  public void add(Vertex v){
    treeMap.putIfAbsent(v.getLocation(), v);
  }

 public Vertex pop() {
    treeMap.get(treeMap.firstKey());  
  }
}
```

This solution:

1. Orders by a `Comparator` that you pass in in your constructor
2. Avoids duplicates by only adding to the map if the key (which is a `Location`) is not present

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll use this.